# Expandin Plugin Function in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, expand

I have ThirstyAffiliate plugin and I want to hook into plugin functions without modifying actual plugin - i just need to expand it from themes functions.php

Here is the actual code: http://codepad.org/4CRudtkj 
and ideally I want to hook in private function save_click_data (so I need plugin to execute it's own code and than mine code that I wrote in functions.php but I need also those variables...at least $thirstylink content)

Now I've placed something like this into functions.php:

```
add_action( 'ta_filter_before_save_click', 'custom_ta_filter_before_save_click', 10,2 );
function custom_ta_filter_before_save_click($thirstylink, $data) {
  global $post;
  global $this;
  print_r($this);
  //execute my few lines after plugin is done with it's stuff....
}
```

Problem is it crashes stating that $this can't be accessed... and $post is always NULL.... So my question is how to actually expand function and get at least post_id or some other identifier.... I really have no idea about OOP, so I need some hints....

Comment: There is another hook in there you could use: `ta_save_click_data`. You'll get access to some meta data (an array) and to the `$thirstylink` object, simply hook into it to do your thing and then return the array without modifications.

Comment: Yap, that was the way to go. Thanks for pointing that out !